# How to filter associated child class based on conditions

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image]

```
public class Cluster {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "cluster_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cluster_id",
        nullable = false,
        updatable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))

 private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

}
```

For example if I have to select all records staring with name "Joh%" in cluster

- whether they have matching records or not in **tag** all cluster records name starting with "Joh%"
  should be selected
- if they have a matching record in **tag** that should be **filtered** based on certain conditions
  ie only tag should be of tag_value grater than 100.

Using Spring boot Jpa specifications.